CSS for image height to print after deducting thead and tfoot
I'm now writing code to auto-print PDFs (in A4 size) from a website. The HTML code of the content is basically in the following structure:
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="headerDiv">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>REVISION</th>
                <th>DOCTYPES</th>
                <th>TITLE</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>Manual</td>
                <td>ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="header-space">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="textOnly">........Very long long texts, may span a few pages...</div>
        <div class="imagesDiv">
          <div class="illus">
            <div class="imageWrapper">
              <img class="imageWidth" src="fig1.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="imageTitle">
              Figure 1
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="illus">
            <div class="imageWrapper">
              <img class="imageWidth" src="fig2.svg">
            </div>
            <div class="imageTitle">
              Figure 2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="footer-space">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<div class="footerDiv">
  <div class="footer">ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.</div>
</div>

The CSS I'm now using is below:
@media print {
    .imageWidth {
        height: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        max-width: 19cm !important;
    }
    .imageWrapper {
        height: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .illus {
        page-break-after: always !important;
    }
    .imageTitle {
        page-break-before: avoid !important;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
    .footerDiv, .footer-space {
        height: 0.5cm;
    }
    .header-space {
        height: 0.2cm;
    }
}

Basically the resulted PDF are having repeated thead table on the top part and footer at the bottom on every pages. The first few pages are the text-only content, then the last few pages are the images, one per each page. The height of the image spans most of the allowable space between the thead table and footer.
The above CSS stylesheet of using height: auto basically working fine, except in the case of the content of the thead table is longer than usual plus the image height (natural height) is taller than usual. For example, if the title is too longer (eg. >10 words) which cause the thead table height grow up to 40px plus the image is taller than 650px, then the image title will be very near (but still a safe distance) the footer statement, then the printed PDF will always come with an empty page after the image. The empty page does not have the thead table, but only include the footerDiv "ALL RIGHTS RESERVED." at the bottom.
I want to get rid of the empty page. I could set the image (mainly the .imageWidth style) size to a smaller but safer size, say height: 17cm;. In that case there's no more extra emty pages, but some of the space between the thead table and footer statement are wasted. I want to use the most of the space remain, so I want to precisely define the height of the image (mainly the .imageWidth style), but it seems I can't find a right way to define it.
I tried to set the height of .imageWidth to 95% or calc(100% - 10px), but seems useless. The use of percentages inside @media print seems not to be functioning, even if I set the height to 10% the image is still the same size. And I found that using percentage may cause a few image pages without the thead table (and that's another problem).
The use of 100vh as many other similar questions suggested do not apply to my case. The images I want now are not spanning the entire page height, but just the entire allowable page height remaining after the thead table and footer are placed. And more importantly, the thead table height are not fixed, it depends on the content length of the table, and so is the image (intrinsic) height.
I'm open to the use of javascript to add/remove/shuffle the DOM elements around, as long as the result PDF is what I want. I have thought to use javascript to get the thead table height first, (eg. document.querySelector("thead").offsetHeight), then I can calculate the remaining space for the image. But I'm not sure how to do it, as I believe the table height is the height of the table printed on the screen, not on the A4 sheet.
